# How to load a subtitle file in VLC for Apple TV

Tags: appletv, vlc

I just got a 4th generation Apple TV and finally I can watch videos on my NAS from Apple TV after I installed VLC.

But I have not found a way to load my own subtitle files. VLC for iPAD has this option, so I just want to know if this is available. The only option I found is to download from `opensubtitle.org`.

Thanks

Comment: Not tried the AppleTV version, but on the Mac all it needs is to be the same name, in the same folder then it will automatically find it - e.g. myMovie.avi & myMovie.srt

Comment: @AskandLearn What happened?

Answer (score 3):

Changing the subtitle file name so that it has the same file name as the movie worked for me.

Comment: Is this really  on appletv? I'm doing this (files served over smb from my mac) and VLC on the Apple TV doesn't find them. VLC on the mac picks them up fine without me doing anything.

Comment: Wow, this really works. I just change the subtitle file name, upload it using Remote Playback and it instantly works.